# Cannot open any Web Projects - Creation of Virtual Directory failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

Win 10, VS 2017.

Trying to open **any** web solution gives the following dialogue box.

[image]

So I am unable to open any projects...

I use the VS 2017 built-in IIS Express.
Does anyone know what is causing this?

On another machine it works fine.

Comment: It would seem that the IISExpress folder had been deleted from Documents.  Is there any way to reset it.

Comment: Can you go and create a new web project, which usually triggers the re-creation of such a folder? However, starting from VS2015, IIS no longer reads configuration files from "My Documents", https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#background You might run a VS Project Diagnostics report and see if common issues can be detected, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Comment: I was just trying that (creation of new project)  Filename: redirection.config.  Error: Cannot read configuration file.  Will investigate your links now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.  It seems the IIS folder was on my OneDrive!?!?  Deleting the folder and create a new ASP.NET Project seems to have fixed the problem.